# Changing global scope objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I have a question about global scope in python.

I make this script and works but I don't know why:

```
#! /bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

data = []
stats = {'white':0, }

def main():
    global data

    with open(args.finput, 'r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()

    rwhitespaces()

    with open(foutput, 'w') as f:
        for line in data:
            f.write(line)

    print(stats)

def rwhitespaces():
    cnt = 0
    for line in data:
        if line == '\n':
            data.pop(cnt) # Modifing data var without global keywork and works, why??
            stats['fistro'] = 1 # Modifing stats var without global keywork and works why??
        cnt += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So I'm misunderstanding something with global scope can someone explain me???
Thanks and sorry my bad english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works because you are not changing the reference, but rather accessing a mutable object, and getting it to perform changes upon itself.

`global` is required to assign a new value to a globally scoped variable (`x = blah`), but it isn't needed to merely access one. As when you do `data.pop(cnt)` all you are doing is accessing the variable, you can do it without using the `global` keyword.

In short, it's not about *changing* properties of the object, it's about *assignment* of an object to a variable.

Comment: Well, it *is* about changing a variable - as opposed to an object's value.

Comment: @delnan I reworded for clarity.